# Bookmarklet to append a string to a URL

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

I tried to insert a link at the beginning of a URL in Chrome using a bookmark. I want the URL to change from:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/csv_example/master/1946_proposicoes.csv
```

To:

```
chrome-extension://ibfcfelnbfhlbpelldnngdcklnndhael/viewer.html?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/csv_example/master/1946_proposicoes.csv
```

I put this in the URL field of a bookmark:

```javascript
javascript:location=location.href.replace(location,"chrome-extension://ibfcfelnbfhlbpelldnngdcklnndhael/viewer.html?url=" + location)
```

But that failed. Then, I tried this:

```javascript
javascript:(function(){window.open('chrome-extension://ibfcfelnbfhlbpelldnngdcklnndhael/viewer.html?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));})();
```

And that also failed.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What errors are thrown?

Comment: There is no error. It just does not change the URL when I hit the bookmark.

Comment: This error is in the console log: `Blocked script execution in 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/csv_example/master/1946_proposicoes.csv' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.`. To open the developer console window on Chrome, use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`J` (on Windows) or `Ctrl`-`Option`-`J` (on Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
javascript:(function() {
    location.href = "chrome-extension://ibfcfelnbfhlbpelldnngdcklnndhael/viewer.html?url=" + location.href;
})();
```

Comment: Nothing changed. And there is more, with each click the javascript console displays this message: _Blocked script execution in 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/csv_example/master/1946_proposicos.csv' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow -scripts' permission is not set._ I also tried after running `google-chrome --args --allow-scripts` in the terminal, and nothing changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this issue. Perhaps this restrictions just can't be overcome.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error

```
Blocked script execution in 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/csv_example/master/1946_proposicoes.csv' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
```

I bumped into this error as well (for a different GitHub URL), and had a look at the HTTP headers that are being served which match very well with the headers returned from my URL:

```
# curl -s -D - -o /dev/null https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kguidonimartins/csv_example/master/1946_proposicoes.csv
HTTP/2 404 
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: deny
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
x-github-request-id: 7CFE:2788:FC6BD:193830:6235F1EF
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Sat, 19 Mar 2022 15:08:54 GMT
via: 1.1 varnish
x-served-by: cache-ams21046-AMS
x-cache: HIT
x-cache-hits: 1
x-timer: S1647702535.805381,VS0,VE0
vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Origin
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-fastly-request-id: a7f167928977f2bff7a2d78679aa13f287777567
expires: Sat, 19 Mar 2022 15:13:54 GMT
source-age: 23
content-length: 14
```

The cause of the error you see is in the first header:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
```

It is documented in [MDN Web Docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) on at [CSP: Sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox):

> The HTTP [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) (CSP) **`sandbox`** directive enables a sandbox for the requested resource similar to the [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute. It applies restrictions to a page's actions including preventing popups, preventing the execution of plugins and scripts, and enforcing a same-origin policy.

By not returning a value for `sandbox`, GitHub tells Chrome that the served page cannot run any scripts. This means that scripts by [Bookmarklets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) are excluded.

I did try finding a setting to workaround this in all the URLs mentioned at [List of Chrome URLs and their purpose - gHacks Tech News](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/09/04/list-of-chrome-urls-and-their-purpose/), but could not find any.

I have not tried it yet, as I don't want a global risk in my Chrome session, but you might use the `--flags --allow-scripts` which for instance is suggested in an answer to [javascript - is triggered for no reason in Chrome - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/923530/noscript-is-triggered-for-no-reason-in-chrome).

So I have to end with that now the cause is explained, but there is no real solution.